# Help with creating more realistic gold material

Tags: rendering, materials, photorealism

i created this gold material by Ryan King  , however, I am still not 100% satisfied with the result. What I am looking for is more realistic real world looking gold material with scratches etc... Can anyone help me please? The figures down below show the shading material and result of it which I currently achieved and last shows the exact gold material that I am looking for my jewelry rendering. Thank you.

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could plug a scratched metal image into the *Roughness* input of your *Principled BSDF* (for the moment you've plugged a texture into the *Base Color* but in my opinion it's the *Roughness* that you should use), and a *Noise* into the *Normal* input. Also use a good HDRI in order to reflect something:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!